# How to extract date only from a file name using C#

Tags: c#, regex, ssis, etl, script-task

I have a situation where I need to extract dates from the file names whose general pattern is `[XXXX_BBBB]_YYYY-MM-DD[.fileExtension]` example `Sales_person_2019-05-03.xlsx`.

I am using c# in the SSIS script task component to achieve this.

below is my code:

```
public void Main()
{

            // TODO: Add your code here
   string pat;
   string date;
   string filename = 'Sales_person_2019-05-03.xlsx'

   // Get the Date part from the file name only
   pat = @"[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}";
   Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   date = r.Match(filename);
   MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());}


    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

but this is not working. Can someone help, please. Newbie on C#

Comment: Basically, I will like to get this date "2019-05-03" in this format "2019/05/02" thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without regular expressions, just use string functions (`IndexOf()` and `Substring()`):

Since you are handling fixed pattern `[XXXX_BBBB]_YYYY-MM-DD[.fileExtension]`, just retrieve the 10 characters located after the second underscore.

```cs
public void Main()
{

    string filename = "Sales_person_2019-05-03.xlsx";

    // Get the Date part from the file name only
    string filedate = filename.Substring(filename.IndexOf('_',filename.IndexOf('_') + 1) + 1,10);

    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(filedate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: @user3011898 if it solve the issue. Feel free to accept it by clicking on the mark on the leftside of the answer